# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined when using select tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React.js.
I'm making a form with a select and option tag.
I made it when some option was selected, setState start with value.
Below is my code

```
class NewAdd extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title:'',
            artist:'',
            day:'',
            genre:'',
            thumbnail:'',
            message: null
        };
    }

    onChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    }

    ...

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Form.Item label="day">
                    <Select name="day" onChange={this.onChange}>
                        <Option value="mon">Monday</Option>
                        <Option value="tue">Tuesday</Option>
                        <Option value="wed">Wednesday</Option>
                    </Select>
                </Form.Item>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

But I got an error..

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
on `this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value}`line.

I don't know what to do ...
I tried separately like

```
this.setState({day:event.target.name});
```

but It didn't work.

I'd appreciate your help.

P.S. I'm using ant design

Comment: I dont know what are you talking about... I'm new on this website and I didnt down vote anyone.... I just clicked check icon at Allen Haley's answer. Is that something wrong?

Comment: and ant design is react UI library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ant Design, `onChange` has `value` parameter but not `event` parameter.

Please try this.

```
    onChange = value => {
        this.setState({ day: value });
    }
```

Please check AntD examples [here](https://ant.design/components/select/).

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming your goal is to set the `state` of `day`, but what you're doing with your code is trying to set `[event.target.name]:` to the value.

`setState()` sets the `state` of a react component, so when you're trying to `setState` of `[event.target.name]:` React doesn't know what you mean because `[event.target.name]:` isn't state.

If you're trying to set the state of day, you will want to do something like this:

```
onChange = (value) =>{
        this.setState({ day: value});
        }
```

your second implementation doesn't work because `event` needs to be `value` not `name`

Answer (score -1):

If you review the Ant Design [documentation](https://ant.design/components/select/), you can see that the onChange function receives as a parameter value:

```
function handleChange(value) {
  console.log(`selected ${value}`);
}

<Select defaultValue="lucy" style={{ width: 120 }} onChange={handleChange}>
```